'sudo' is not known in line 2 in sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal.xenial.list?
I am trying to update Ubuntu but when I follow the website instructions the following message appears:-
'sudo' is not known in line 2 in sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal.xenial.list
What can I do?
Thanks.

Line 2 of the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal.xenial.list  contains error(s); you need to correct that. sudo is a command, where that file should contain source details (not commands).  That file was added to your system post-install, and needs correction.

@guiverc Thanks. Can you give me instructions on how to correct my error in Line 2? It would be much appreciated,

We're limited to details you provide, your error message specifically mentions line 2 and the file with the error, but not what is in that file. If it was me, I'd jump to terminal and edit the file directly using sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal.xenial.list which allows you to view and edit that file; however vim is not what most consider an easy editor, but it was useful early 80s as it allowed editing files before arrow-keys on keyboards became the norm... Use whatever editor you're familiar with; be it a GUI editor if using desktop, or terminal editor if using server....

You've also not provided your OS/release details, so I can't give specifics there... xenial is the codename for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which is EOSS, but I'm aware some third party sources still use that EOL/EOSS codename for newer systems, but again you've provided no specifics. Official Ubuntu docs can be read at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu which maybe easier/harder than the duplicate link that exists on this site.

Thank you for you advice @guiverc. In terminal I used your sudo vim sequence but is does not recognise vim. I have tried copying the 'problem report' here but cannot seem to be able to get it to copy here. My version of Ubuntu is 22.04. It is on my laptop. Should I give up now and take it to someone to fix, or can you advise further? Much appreciated.

vim is a version of the old vi editor (I learnt in the 80s because terminals at University usually didn't have arrow keys, and vi coped with that), but nano or other editors will work too. Depending on what product you have installed you can have different editors (mine installed with vim, others with vi, some with nano etc.. and you've not said what you're using, though have no given release as 22.04 which is part detail; no Server/Desktop etc). Use whatever editor you have installed, or use cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal.xenial.list to view contents

and edit it using the same method you used to create the file in the first place (ie. overwrite it with correction for example). Editing the line & adding a "#" at the start of the line turns the line into a comment; ie. easier to revert than deleting the line outright.. but you can fix anyway you deem appropriate. I can't see what's on your screen so can't help.. My detail is limited to what you provide in your question.
